# Open popup before View is loaded and only load the view after the popup closes

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I could use some help here. I have a fullscreen app. I am looking to open a popup on load of the application and before the view is loaded. Based on the actions taken on the popup I want the view to be loaded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share some code with what you have tried?

Comment: @Quilture I'm afraid I cant share my code. All I have done is created and opened a popup onBeforeRendering event. What this effectively does is create's a popup and loads my view in the meantime. I want to load the view after the user takes an action on the popup

Comment: Why not have an empty view which opens the popup, and then based on the popup action navigate to the actual view?

Comment: @Qualiture - Thanks a lot! This was on the back of my mind, but I was really hoping to not involve another view. But it looks like this is the only way forward as I dont think any API's exists to stop the painting of the screen until a user action occurs. Much appreciated.

Comment: That is true. The old-fashioned javascript alert behavior is totally overboard now, everything works asynchronous :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to find the solution of the question. The popup couldn't open on onInit as its after that the rest of the DOM structure of the page loads. The sap.m.Dialog which actually depends on the container size to render suddenly finds that it's container has changed and tries to render accordingly, fails to do so and disappears. What needs to be done is open the popup onAfterRendering. The skeletal UI would be loaded in the background. Only after taking a decision on the popup should you proceed with loading any of the actual data and updating the view.

Answer (score 1):

yes! you can.
Don't add the UI content which has dependency on the actions taken from the popup.

Steps:

- Create a popup in `onInit` function of your fullscreen view
  controller.
- Based on the action(s) create and add the content to your
  view.

> Note: UI rendering using js view would be slower compared to rendering
>   via XML views

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sunil,
I have fairly complex views and doing such would just decrease the performance of my app. Also this would defeat the purpose of a view in my opinion

Comment: you can always render the common UI skeleton..
As per my assumption, your OData calls have dependency on the action on your popup. If this is the case, avoid direct binding in UI and do bind it in controller.

Comment: Nevertheless I can understand the complexity level!
another workaround is that loading the popup in your Main.controller.js
You may face hiccups there!

Comment: Yes Sunil you are right. Thats how my app works. I did try invoking the same in the Main controller but that had its own issues! Thanks for the help in any case

Comment: Sunil you were definitely on the right track. But instead of loading it onInit it should be loaded onAfterRendering event.